# Applescript-how can I expand a list view window's contents so everything shows hierarchically and expanded

Tags: macos, finder, applescript

Given a root directory upon selection, I need to traverse the directory and all other subdirectories, expanding all subfolders, so that everything shows hierarchically in the finder's list view.

This answer [select-all-non-folders-in-an-expanded-list-view-window](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/218556/applescript-how-can-i-select-all-non-folders-in-an-expanded-list-view-window/218751#218751) acts to select all items in an expanded view.

I need to expand all subfolders, until all subfolders from the root directory have been expanded, showing the contents of the root folder and all subfolders hierarchically.

Answer (score 1):

You can expand all sub-directories with an alt-click on the arrow left of your directory. [image: Directories]